# Return column headers if cells are empty

Tags: vba, excel, multiple-columns

[image: Sample of the Worksheet]

The worksheet has approximately 100 column headers and more than 800 rows. I want to use a function or create a macro which will pick up column headers and summarize these headers in a separate column, separated by commas.

Using row 2 of the screenshot above as an example, Criteria 2, Criteria 5 and Criteria 7 are empty. I would like to display these missing criteria in column named "Missing" with the value being "Criteria 2, Criteria 5, Criteria 7".

Comment: Show us what you have tried and where you have run into problems.  If you have Excel 2016, you can use the `TEXTJOIN` function with no need for VBA.

Answer (score 0):

This code add new sheet, and show the Result.

```
Sub test()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet, outWs As Worksheet
    Dim vDB, vR(), vResult()
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, i As Long, j As Long

    Set Ws = ActiveSheet
    With Ws
        r = .Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        c = .Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
        vDB = .Range("a1", .Cells(r, c))
    End With
    ReDim vResult(1 To r, 1 To 4)
    For i = 1 To r
        n = 0
        For j = 1 To c
            If j < 4 Then
                vResult(i, j) = vDB(i, j)
            End If
            If IsEmpty(vDB(i, j)) Then
                n = n + 1
                ReDim Preserve vR(1 To n)
                vR(n) = vDB(1, j)
            End If
        Next j
        vResult(i, 4) = Join(vR, ",")
    Next i
    vResult(1, 4) = "Missing"
    Set outWs = Sheets.Add '<~~ your specific sheets : Sheet("your sheet name")
    With outWs
        .Range("a1").Resize(r, 4) = vResult
        .Columns.AutoFit
    End With
End Sub
```